# How to set inherited variable in java?

Tags: java, class, inheritance, extends

```
public class Atribut {
int classid;

@Override public String toString() {
return Integer.toString(classid);


}

}
```

I have made this class which overrides method toString(). I plan on making many subclasses with different classid. The problem is I dont know how to set the variable classid to work in toString method.

```
public class cas extends Atribut{
int classid=2;


}
```

The problem is if I make an cas object and toString method it returns "0" not "2".??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Much as @java_mouse recommended, just use the parent class's variable.

```
public class Atribut {
    protected int classid;

    public Atribut() {
        classid = 0;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return Integer.toString(classid);
    }    
}

public class Cas extends Atribut{
    public Cas() {
        classid = 2;
    }
}
```

Set `classid`'s value in the constructor and then you can use the superclass's `toString()` just fine.

Answer (score 8):

My preferred technique for this kind of thing is to use constructor arguments:

```
public class Parent {
    // Using "protected final" so child classes can read, but not change it
    // Adjust as needed if that's not what you intended
    protected final int classid;

    // Protected constructor: must be called by subclasses
    protected Parent(int classid) {
        this.classid = classid;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return Integer.toString(classid);
    }
}

public class Child extends Parent {
    public Child() {
        // The compiler will enforce that the child class MUST provide this value
        super(2); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

When you shadow the variable, the one in the parent class is used in methods there.

If you want to do this, I would do this

```
class Atribut {
    int classid = 0;

    protected int classid() { return classid; } // points to Attribut.classid
    public String toString() {
        return Integer.toString(classid());
    }

}
```

Then in your child class, you can override the method

```
class cas {
    int classid = 2;
    protected int classid() { return classid; } // points to cas.classid
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why do you want to shadow a variable in child class if it is already available in the parent? why not using the same variable?

if you use the same variable, the issue is resolved automatically. Don't duplicate the attribute if it has to be inherited.

Answer (score 0):

I think most of the answers here narrow down to **style preference**.
For such small examples, most of the provided solutions would work just fine.
However, let's assume that you have an inheritance tree that is several levels deep. In such a scenario, it might be challenging to understand the source of each property, so using setters, getters, and references to the superclass might come in handy. My personal choice would be as follows:

```
public class Atribut {

    private int firstProp;
    private int thirdProp;

    public int getFirstProp() {
        return firstProp;
    }

    public void setFirstProp(int firstProp) {
        this.firstProp = firstProp;
    }

    ....

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return Integer.toString(this.getFirstProp()) +
               Integer.toString(this.getThirdProp());
    }
}

public class Cas extends Atribut {

    private int secondProp;

    public Cas() {
        super.setFirstProp(1);
        this.setSecondProp(2);
        super.setThirdProp(3);
    }
}
```

An alternative implementation, using the approaches provided above would result in the this Cas class:

```
public Cas() {
    super(1, 3)
    secondProp = 2;
}
```

This second solution is a bit harder to read and is less descriptive about what properties are you setting.

For those reasons, that is the style that I prefer. Also, to reiterate, the benefits of the first approach become more evident for more complex examples.